# Simple C# web application with a database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have been at this for about 3 weeks now and have read and watched so many videos in youtube, which I followed to the T but none worked for me. At this point I'm pulling my hairs out.

Website come's out alright in web browser but when textboxes are filled and submit button is hit database stay's empty.

So this is what I have:

=========================== **Original** ===========================

## Database Column Fields:

```
FirstName 
MiddleName
LastName 
Email
Phone 
BTTR
BDTR
Issues
```

**Page**

```
First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="First_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Your First Name!" />
Middle Name:<asp:TextBox ID="Middle_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Optional" />
Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="Last_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" />
Email Address:<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" />
Phone:<asp:TextBox ID="Phone" runat="server" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" />


Good day to reach you:
<asp:DropDownList ID="BDTR" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Mondays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Tuesdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Wednesdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Thursdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Fridays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Saturdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sundays</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Good time to reach you:
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" name="BTTR" ID="BTTR">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="1">Select One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="6-8" Value="2">6am - 8am </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="8-10" Value="3">8am - 10am</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="10-12" Value="4">10am - Noon</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="12-2" Value="5">Noon - 2pm</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="2-4" Value="6">2pm - 4pm</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="4-6" Value="7">4pm - 6pm</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Please describe your health issues:
<asp:TextBox runat="server" name="Issues" id="Issues"  placeholder="Examples: Remember the more details you can provide the better we can help you" />

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="special" /><asp:Label ID="ConfLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></li>
```

**Code page**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Survey_Build_Platform : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            ConfLabel.Text = ("*** Thank you - Your request has been submitted");
        }
    }
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=win-ngvi5b6ngjv/sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MOBILEMED;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 3DayTrial(RefferalName, ReferralCodeValues(@First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Phone, @BTTR, @BDTR, @Issues)", cnn);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middle_Name", Middle_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eMail", Email.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", Cell_Phone.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BTTR", BTTR.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BDTR", BDTR.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issues", Goals.Text);

            cnn.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

=========================== **Modified** ===========================

Software:

- Windows 8 with IIS installed
- SQL 2012 Express Edition
- Visual Studio Community Edition

**Database Column Fields:**

```
ID --- (INT)
FirstName --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
MiddleName --- NvarChar (50)
LastName --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
Email --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
Phone --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
GTTR --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
GDTR --- NvarChar (50, no Nulls)
Issues --- NvarChar (MAX)
```

**PAGE**

```
First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="First_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Your First Name!" />
Middle Name:<asp:TextBox ID="Middle_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Optional" />
Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="Last_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" />
Email Address:<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" />
Phone:<asp:TextBox ID="Phone" runat="server" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" />


Good day to reach you:
<asp:DropDownList ID="GDTR" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Mondays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Tuesdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Wednesdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Thursdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Fridays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Saturdays</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sundays</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Good time to reach you:
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" name="GTTR" ID="BTTR">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="1">Select One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="6-8" Value="2">6am - 8am </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="8-10" Value="3">8am - 10am</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="10-12" Value="4">10am - Noon</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="12-2" Value="5">Noon - 2pm</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="2-4" Value="6">2pm - 4pm</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="4-6" Value="7">4pm - 6pm</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Please describe your health issues:
<asp:TextBox runat="server" name="Issues" id="Issues"  placeholder="Examples: Remember the more details you can provide the better we can help you" />

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="special" onclick="Submit_Click" /><asp:Label ID="ConfLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

**Code page**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Survey_Build_Platform : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            ConfLabel.Text = ("*** Thank you - Your request has been submitted");
        }
    }
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=win-ngvi5b6ngjv/sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SMCMEDC;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SMCMEDC (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Email, Phone, GTTR, GDTR, Goals) VALUES (@First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Phone, @GTTR, @GDTR, @Issues)", cnn);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", First_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", Middle_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Last_Name.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Cell_Phone.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GTTR", GTTR.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GDTR", GDTR.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issues", Goals.Text);

            cnn.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int count = xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
             if (count != 1)
               {
                 ConfLabel.Text = ("*** Something went wrong");
               }
            cnn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: Good, so you know how to dump code on us. Anything you want to ASK? Because, if you read all your text... there is no question.

Comment: Is AutoEventWireUp to set to True in your page directive? It probably is, but worth checking.

Comment: Sorry, my first post here. anyway i am pulling my hairs out because i really don't know what's going wrong. the page is coming out right on web browser and i fill in the text boxes but the the database stay's empty.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO 3DayTrial(RefferalName, ReferralCodeValues(@First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Phone, @GTTR, @GDTR, @Issues)
```

This does not look like valid SQL to me.  Insert statements typically have one of

- Values clause
- Select statement

So I would expect your SQL to look like this:

```
 INSERT INTO 3DayTrial
 VALUES (@First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Phone, @GTTR, @GDTR, @Issues)
```

or

```
 INSERT INTO 3DayTrial
 SELECT @First_Name, @Middle_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Phone, @GTTR, @GDTR, @Issues
```

You might also need a field list -- but we can't know that because you did not show us very important information.  The table names and table create statements -- to really understand what is going on we would need to see that too.

---

Consider some error checking.  The line

```
xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Should probably be

```
int count = xp.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (count != 1)
{
   // handle insert error
}
```

I suggest that you ALWAYS check return values if you are calling a function that returns a value.  No harm will come of it and you will be writing much better code.

Comment: Thanks, checking your solution now.

Comment: okay i edited the Insert statement but I'm getting an error on the - if (count != 1)      Count is being identified as an error: Does not exist in the current context

Comment: you need both lines... you need to have the `int count =` part too.

Comment: ahh...   i saw xp.ExecuteNonQuery(); and i assumed i only needed to insert the if statement       ------    cnn.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int count = xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count != 1)
           {
                // handle insert error
           }
        cnn.Close();

Comment: NO!  replace `xp.ExecuteNonQuery();` with `int count = xp.ExecuteNonQuery();` THIS IS VERY BASIC.  You need to take a basic programming class if you think calling a function twice here makes sense.  I understand we are helping you but you are going to have to think.  There is no "autopilot" in programming.

Comment: Would changing the following make a difference?                             "INSERT INTO SMCMEDC (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Email, Phone, GTTR, GDTR, Goals) VALUES....

Comment: Oh sorry i did remove the extra xp.executenonquery() on my code i just copied and pasted on the board. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: no idea... change it from what?

Comment: I mean, i had it from "Insert Into SMCMEDC Values (..."    to "Insert into SMCMEDC (First_Name, Middle_Name.....) Values (...." ---- Adding the textbox ID's. is this unnecessary/wrong (just saw something similar done on an example). there's so many examples online but all of them have not worked because of incomplete instructions or no instructions at all, and most have no references i can read.

Comment: I already answered that in my answer, you are talking about a "field list". As I said, you might need one... I don't know because you have not shown us the details of your tables and how they are defined.  In general, it can't hurt to have a field list included in your insert statement.  You often have to be quite tricky to not need one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience. i really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a click method defined for your button. As coded this button doesn't do anything except cause a postback. The Submit_Click method will not execute. You need to read and learn about break points in debugging. If you had stepped through your code you would have discovered your method never fires.

You need to add `onclick="Submit_Click"` to your button code.

Then you will soon discover that the answer that Hogan provided will fix the problem encountered when the click event happens.

Comment: nice... missed that ... but I remember that `runat="server"` auto wires up some code -- is it possible the function is called in that way?

Comment: okay, don't laugh at me for being a noob here. but where do you put the      onclick="Submit_Click", is it in the page code on the     <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="special" onclick="Submit_Click" />       ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can also use the front end to add it if you want. Just double click the button in design view. Or you can go the properties tab for the button, click on events, then chose the event in the drop down under the click event.

Comment: You should also be careful using AddWithValue. When you are not using stored procedures (I would highly recommend over inline sql) it can sometimes get the datatypes incorrect which will drive you nuts. If you stick with inline sql you should define the datatype to avoid this issue.

Comment: @SeanLange - everything is a varchar -- add with value should be fine.

Comment: @Hogan right but since they are obviously very new I want to warn them because they will likely use this as an example for their next project and that nasty thing may well rear its ugly head and make the poor OP scratch their head as to what went wrong.

Comment: I actually just copied the AddWithValue form another example i found on youtube. I don't know much about store procedures yet, I will look into it once i get this project working.